# systemd Failed at step EXEC spawning script: Permission denied

Tags: shell-script, rhel, systemd, services

I am attempting to create a "Hello World" service, so to speak. It is called `autologger.service` and is store at `/usr/lib/systemd/system/autologger.service`.

I attempted `sudo service autologger start`, but `systemctl` returned the standard:

```
Job for autologger.service failed. See 'systemctl status
autologger.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

When I checked `/var/log/messages`, I saw the following error message:

`Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/autologger/placeholder.sh: Permission denied`

My question is: how do I give a service permissions to anything?

Here is the service unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello World
DefaultDependencies=no
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target


[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/autologger/placeholder.sh
```

placeholder.sh simply contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I forgot the fundamentals....

```
chmod +x placeholder.sh
```